# How to find sum of files for all directories and sub directories (separately) and them sort them by size

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Could you please advise me how to find the sum of all files in directories and sub directories?
I try to make this script but is not working.

```
find . -xdev -type d  | while read l;do ls -l "$l" |
  awk '{sum+=$5}END{print sum/1024/1024 "" $l }';done | sort -k 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is which program expands which variable. You expect the shell to expand the $l in your awk-command, but the awk command is in single quotes and therefore the shell does not expand $l.

Passing $l as a variable to awk should solve your problem:

```sh
find . -xdev -type d |
while read l; do
  ls -l "$l" |
  awk -v "l=$l" ' {sum+=$5} END{print sum " " l} '
done |
sort -n
```

Comment: wow thanks  mate now is working I guess. Will test it next few days

Comment: find . -xdev -type d  | while read l; do ls -l "$l" | grep -v '^d'|grep -v '^t'|  awk -v "l=$l" '{sum+=$5}END{print sum/1024/1024 "    " l}';done | sort -k 1 -n

Answer (score 1):

There's already a tool in the Unix toolbox for this. You don't have to reinvent the wheel:

```
du -x -s * | sort -n
```

Your du(1) manual page (for *disk usage*) has all the bells and whistles explained.

Comment: [root@home install]# du -x -s * | wc -l
35
[root@home install]# find . -type d |wc -l
7688
[root@home install]# 
This command is not checking sub directories. I want to find sup directories

Comment: @user3661564 just remove the `-s`. so, `du -x | wc -l` gives for me `36`. The `find . -type d -print | wc -l` also `36`. :) Sometimes is helpful read some manual. (in this case for the `du`) :) :)

Comment: but in this case you also take into account sub directories

Comment: @user3661564 But that's what you state in your question: *"how to find sum of all files in directories and sub directories"*.

Comment: I mean sum only of file for each directory not sum of files of directory plus sub directory anyway we have solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3661564 Ah, ok. That would be `find . -xdev -type d|xargs du -s|sort -n`.

Answer (score 0):

The awk command is in the wrong place.  It should come after the while loop.

Comment: but then will sum all directories size

Comment: That's exactly what the original question asked.